# Traverse a Hexagon

Tags: javascript

I can easily traverse the following from left to right, but I'm having a lot of trouble (2 days in, and no progress) getting a formula to traverse it from top right & bottom right.

[image]

Basically, I'm looking for a formula which can retrieve the following values:

```
let topRight = [
    [ h[2][4], h[3][3], h[4][2] ],
    [ h[1][3], h[2][3], h[3][2], h[4][1] ],
    [ h[0][2], h[1][2], h[2][2], h[3][1], h[4][0] ],
    [ h[0][1], h[1][1], h[2][1], h[3][0] ],
    [ h[0][0], h[1][0], h[2][0] ]
]

let bottomRight = [
    [ h[2][4], h[1][3], h[0][2] ],
    [ h[3][3], h[2][3], h[1][2], h[0][1] ],
    [ h[4][2], h[3][2], h[2][2], h[1][1], h[0][0] ],
    [ h[4][1], h[3][1], h[2][1], h[1][0] ],
    [ h[4][0], h[3][0], h[2][0] ]
]
```

The only part that I could get working was the `topRight` x value:

```
function hexagonArraySize(row) {
  if (row < this.size) {
    return (this.size + row)
  } else {
    return (this.size * 2 - (row % this.size) - 2)
  }
}

for (var i = 0, l = this.size * 2 - 1, j = l % size; i < l; ++i, ++j) {
  this.h[j] = new Array(this.hexagonArraySize(i)).fill().map((_, b) => {
    let x = (i > Math.floor(this.size / 2)) ? b : b + (this.size - i - 1)
    let y = 0 // didn't found the formula for this one...
  }, []).join("")
}
```

I made a fiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/0qwf8m1p/12/

There still is `topRight` y, `bottomRight` x & y to be found.

Comment: Will you always use this same size of grid? Or do you need to be more general for any size grid?

Comment: The intention is from size 3 to 15. So general.

Comment: For the given example, look for patterns in specific cases. For example, start at (0, 0) and move down and to the right. What is the next grid? And the next one? Can you see a pattern after these two? Try the same movement with the next larger hex grid? Does the same pattern hold? Keep going down to the right. When does the pattern change for both sizes of grid?

Comment: What's blows the pattern is when you are going from the bottomRight diagonal, you get the following pattern `h[4][1], h[3][1], h[2][1], h[1][0]`, so, why does it repeat the y = 1 three times, and then goes to zero ? Also, in the topRight diagonal, it has the following pattern `h[0][2], h[1][2], h[2][2], h[3][1], h[4][0]` which repeats y = 2 three times... I can't find correlations on top of that... Maybe repeat the number the size of the hexagon? But that get's busted when we see the following pattern: `h[1][3], h[2][3], h[3][2], h[4][1]` which only repeat 2 times the number 3...

Comment: If you want to make your life easier, "fill up" the hexagon with tiles in the TL && BR or TR&&BL corner, and think of it as a skewed 2d grid *(with some empty/unused cells)*. So, your first row could start at `0,2`, the second row at `1,1` and all your x-coordinates would align along the tl,br diagonal.

Comment: @joaumg in both cases, when does the pattern change?

Comment: Sorry, I still can't find the pattern. I'm adding a fiddle and a bounty on this one...

Comment: Could the formula operate based on screen coordinates? By that I mean, would such a solution be acceptable?

Comment: I don't have time to code it until tomorrow, but pattern is quite simple, just look at how far is your starting point from middle (also largest) row and how your steps change after you pass middle. For example, bottomRight[2]... 4 -> last one, 3 -> last one - 1, 2(middle) -> last one - 2 and rest of them, after you "pass" the middle row are 1 -> last one - 2, 0 -> last one - 2... So, every next step is one place to the left until you pass middle, then is same number of steps to the left as for the middle row. It's symmetrical for toRight and don't forget to check if step exists for [3] & [4]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so you worked out `topRight` `x` coordinate.

Both `topRight` and `bottomRight` `y` coordinates have the same equation:

- You start with `(size - 1) * 2`
- First value always equals `(size - 1) * 2 - i)` (where `i` is the sequence index)
- Then you repeat first value `i` times, but at most `size` times

This wraps up to the following formula:

```
let y = (size - 1) * 2 - i - Math.max(0, b - Math.min(i, size - 1))
        |                  |                                      |
        |    first value   |      repeat at most size times       |
```

---

Next, you have to calculate `x` value for `bottomRight`. You have two cases here:

- If `i` is less than `size / 2` then value equals sequence length - `b` (item index)
- Otherwise value equals `(size - 1) * 2 - b`

This wraps up to the following formula:

```
let x = (i > Math.floor(size / 2)) ? (size - 1) * 2 - b : hexagonArraySize(i) - b - 1
        |                          |                    |
        |       check index        |     second half    |          first half
```

---

**[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0qwf8m1p/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation for the two methods. They work by initializing the `x,y` coordinates of the start for each row in the transformed hexagon, then conditionally iterate the `x` value based on whether or not the `y` value passed the `size` of the hexagon, where the indices "bend":

```js
function hexagon (size) {
  const height = size * 2 - 1;
  
  return Array.from({ length: height }, (_, y) => {
    const width = size + Math.min(y, height - y - 1);
    
    return Array.from({ length: width }, (_, x) => [y, x]);
  })
}

const h = hexagon(3);

function topRight (h) {
  const height = h.length;
  const size = (height + 1) / 2;
  const t = [];
  
  for (let i = height; i > 0; i--) {
    const width = size + Math.min(i - 1, height - i);
    const row = Array.from({ length: width });
    
    let y = Math.max(i - size, 0);
    let x = i - 1;
    
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      row[j] = h[y++][y >= size ? x-- : x];
    }
    
    t.push(row);
  }
  
  return t;
}

function bottomRight (h) {
  const height = h.length;
  const size = (height + 1) / 2;
  const t = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    const width = size + Math.min(i, height - i - 1);
    const row = Array.from({ length: width });
    
    let y = height - Math.max(size - i, 1);
    let x = height - i - 1;
    
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      row[j] = h[y][y-- < size ? x-- : x];
    }

    t.push(row);
  }
  
  return t;
}

console.log('topRight');
topRight(h).forEach(row => console.log(JSON.stringify(row)));
console.log('bottomRight');
bottomRight(h).forEach(row => console.log(JSON.stringify(row)));
```

If you'd like a more object-oriented approach, here's a possible alternative:

```js
class Hexagon extends Array {
  constructor (size, map = (row, column) => [row, column]) {
    const length = size * 2 - 1;
    
    super(length);
    
    this.fill();
    this.size = size;
    this.forEach((_, row, hexagon) => {
      const width = size + Math.min(row, length - row - 1);
      hexagon[row] = Array.from({ length: width }, (_, column) => map(row, column));
    });
  }
  
  topRight () {
    const { length, size } = this;
    return new Hexagon(size, (row, column) => {
      const upper = Math.max(row * 2 - length, 0) + 1;
      const y = Math.max(size - 1 - row, 0) + column;
      const x = Math.max(Math.min(length - 1 - row, length - upper - column), 0);
      return this[y][x];
    });
  }
  
  bottomRight () {
    const { length, size } = this;
    return new Hexagon(size, (row, column) => {
      const upper = Math.max(row * 2 - length, 0) + 1;
      const y = Math.min(size + row, length) - 1 - column;
      const x = Math.max(Math.min(length - 1 - row, length - upper - column), 0);
      return this[y][x];
    });
  }
}

let h = new Hexagon(3);
console.log('topRight');
h.topRight().forEach(row => console.log(JSON.stringify(row)));
console.log('bottomRight');
h.bottomRight().forEach(row => console.log(JSON.stringify(row)));
```